# Why was my footbal (soccer) team transferred to another division?

Tags: powerplay-manager

Yesterday was the start of a new football (soccer) season in this game. My team was transferred to another league, from IV.6 - IV.10. So it's still in the 4th league but why another "division"?

Comment: Please add comments to help me improve my posts for future, thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

As far as I could see the reason is the same as the one in real life/football:
 - divisions should have similar number of teams
 - teams should be allocated to divisions according to geographical positions

So for example if in one year your IV.6 was having too many teams, some are distributed to other divisions which are closer to them (geographically).

The reason behind this is to reduce the cost of travelling for small clubs.

Comment: Yes, I absolutely understand conditions in real world, but why in manager simulation? Game has not include traveling to oponent stadions,